# Cannot use accessors in extended classes

Tags: oop, accessor

I have a program that creates an array list of Plants, there are three classes which extend Plant: Flower, Fungus, and Weed.

All three subclasses share 3 qualities, whose methods are in the Plant class.  I am able to easily access these out of my arraylist using, myList.get(i).getPlantName.  getPlantName is an accessor method inside of the plant class.

The subclasses have unique qualities, for example, the Flower Class has qualities like, hasThorns and hasSmell.  I am UNABLE to access these accessors though.  I thought I would be able to write something like myList.get(i).getHasSmell.  getHasSmell is a method defined in my flower class (Flower is an extended class of Plant).

Most of my program works great, I'm able to create objects of the extended classes, the only thing I am unable to do is use the accessor methods in the extended classes, as described in the paragraph above.

Why am I unable to use these accessors in my extended classes?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What programming language are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it you're trying to access methods defined on the child classes, which don't exist in the parent class.

In order to access those methods, the parent class (Plant) will either need to define the method (either in a concrete fashion such as Plant.hasSmell() { return false; } or as an abstract method) and be overridden in the child class OR provide some way for you to determine what child class to cast the Plant object to in order to call that method.

E.g. An enumeration in Plant for the type of plant (Weed, Flower, Fungus), and a switch to do the cast.

Personally I would suggest the abstract method in the parent class as the preferred approach.